# Chained Selects with Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I new to programming, and have just finished the jquery course on CodeAcademy.I'm currently trying to create a chained select using Jquery's AJAX function to call a php page which runs a query on my database and echoes it out to my main html page.

Currently, I am able to load only my first , the second and third selects do not seem to be working, and i do not know what exactly it is that i'm doing wrong.

Jquery Code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#category").load("AddItemCat.php");
});

$("#category").onchange(function(){
    var category=$("#category").val();
    $("#subcat").load("AddItemSubCat.php?category="+category);
});

$("#subcat").onchange(function(){
    var category=$("#category").val();
    var subcat=$("#subcat").val();
    $("#subcat").load("AddItemSubCat.php?category="+category+"&subcat="+subcat);
});
```

My HTML Form:

```
<form action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" name="edititem" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
  Category:
    <select name="category" id="category" ></select>



  SubCategory:
    <select id="subcat" name="subcat"></select>


  Item:
    <select id="item" name="item"></select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Item Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="itemname" size="30" maxlength="50" required="required"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Item Price</td>
  <td><input type="number" name="itemprice" size="30" min="1" required="required"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Item Info</td>
  <td><textarea name="iteminfo" col="40" rows="10" maxlength="300" required="required"></textarea>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Filename:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="upload[]" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Filename:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="upload[]" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Filename:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="upload[]" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Filename:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="upload[]" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Filename:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="upload[]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2"><input type="SUBMIT" name="Button" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><?PHP if(isset($errormsg)){echo"$errormsg";}?></td>
</tr>       
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"><font color="#FF0000"></font></td>            
</tr>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake and give me pointers on rectifying it.Thanks!

Comment: Too much of code.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way to much code to help you but since you say that the jQuery part does not work:

```
$("#category").onchange(function(){
```

This should be

```
("#category").on("change", function(){
```

There is no `onchange` in jQuery 1.10 (or any other version?). A brief look into the console would have shown you the error I guess. Additionally, you shoud put all your other calls inside `$(document).ready` as well.

Answer (score 0):

try use page url instead of file name. e.g - `url to AddItemSubCat.php`